# Linear Spaces, Bases $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $S,T : R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is a linear transformation.

Is it necessary true that $T = S$ if  $KerT = KerS$ and $ImT = ImS$

Well, I thought showing that It's not necessary true by saying:

$T(x,y) = (x,y)$ and $S(x,y) = (2x,2y)$

If we take a vector now in $R^2$, let it be $(1,1)$ which means $x=1 , y=1$ then

$T(1,1) = (1,1)$ and $S(1,1) = (2,2)$

So we can see that the kernel of $T$ is $(1,1)$ and the kernel of S is $(1,1)$ which are equal.

And we can say that $(1,1) = (2,2)$ because they are both in $ImT$ and $ImT$ are vectors which span $ImT$ which means we can say that $(2,2)$ is a span of $(1,1)$ so the images are equal.

And thus,kernels and images are equal. About $T=S$, it's not necessary true because

If we take a matrix A $(2x2)$ and multiply it once by $(x,y)$ in linear transformation T we will get a $(2x1)$ vector, which will be different if we multiply it by $(2x,2y)$.

So, $T = S$ isn't necessary true.

I think I'm wrong or my explanation is wrong, Can anyone help me to understand with a good counterexample that $T = S$ isn't necessary true while $KerT=KerS $and $ImT = ImS $ ?

Comment: Your example is fine, as far as I can see. For two functions (linear or whatever) to be different it is enough that they don't agree on one single value, and your $\;T,S\;$ don't agree on $\;(1,1)\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Any chance you can explain it in another way or explain a little more? I'm having difficulties understanding what I just wrote although it should be, theoretically right. weird I know.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong, but the example is good. You say, for example, that $(1,1)$ is in the kernel of these maps. Is it? What is the definition of kernel?

Comment: that for every vector  $v$ in $KerT$, $T(v) = (0,0)$.

Comment: In order to be *identical*, two functions $\;T\,,\,S\;$  must have the very same domain and, for **all** $\;x\;$ in this domain it must be that $\;T(x)=S(x)\;$ . You gave an example in which the domain is the same but $\;T(1,1)\neq S(1,1)\;$ and thus $\;T\neq S\;$ as functions.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think I Got it now, if $kerT=KerS$ then $T(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $S(x,y) = (0,0)$ which means $x=y=0$. Right? and for images I exaplained it right because for $x=y=1$, the $(2,2)$ is a span of $(1,1)$ but $T \ne S$ because $T(1,1) \ne T(2,2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are right and your example is good, but you have some mistakes in what you wrote. The kernel is $\ker(T)=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid T(v)=(0,0)\}$ so in your example you have $\ker(T)=\ker(s)=\{(0,0)\}$. Also, $\mathrm{Im}(T)=\mathrm{Im}(S)=\mathbb{R}^2$ in your example (show this!) so your assumptions hold, but $S\neq T$. To show that two linear transformations are different it is enough to exhibit a vector $v$ such that $T(v)\neq S(v)$, so for example: $T((1,1))=(1,1)\neq (2,2)=S((1,1))$.

Comment: I show in my example that $(1,1) = (2,2)$ in $ImT$ because $ImT$ is a span of vectors, thus $(2,2) = 2*(1,1)$. Right?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, you have some basic misunderstanding. $(1,1)\neq (2,2)$ because these are two *different* vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. They are linearly dependant, this is a different equivalence relation.

Comment: I also can write I guess that for every $u$ in $R^2$ and for every $v$ in $R^2$, I can say $T(u) = v$, and $S(u) = v$. Therefore, $T(u) = S(u)$ and Thus, $ImT = ImS$? @DKal

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, no you cannot write this! what you can write is that for every $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ **there exist** vectors $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(v_1)=u$ and $S(v_2)=u$ and therefore $\mathrm{Im}(T)=\mathbb{R}^2=\mathrm{Im}(S)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I quite got it.

Comment: about the Kernel, that v in R^2 must be zero right? because only T(v) = S(v) = 0 when the vector is zero or it for every v, or just there is v that T(v) = S(v) = 0?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, let $(x,y)\in\ker(T)$, so $T((x,y))=(0,0)$, therefore $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Similarly, let $(x,y)\in\ker(S)$ so $S((x,y))=(0,0)$, therefore $(2x,2y)=(0,0)$ and thus $(x,y)=(0,0)$.